# Returning a Value from a Recursive Python Function

Tags: python, function, recursion

*Edit: I should have said up front that I know this isn't the best way to do it; I was specifically trying to use recursion for this to learn about it.*

I'm new to Python with beginner knowledge of programming and I'm running into an issue with recursion and error-handling. I have this function that takes user input to get a variable for my program:

```
1    def get_seconds():
2        a = input("Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? ")
3        if a.lower() == "q":
4            exit()
5        try:
6            int_a = int(a)
7            if int_a < 1 or int_a > 60:
8                print("Interval must be between 1 and 60.")
9                get_seconds()
10               return(int_a)
11           else:
12               return(int_a)
13       except:
14           print("Interval must be an integer between 1 and 60.")
15           get_seconds()
16    
17   c = get_seconds()
18   print(c)
```

The idea is that if the user inputs Q or q, it quits immediately. If the user inputs a number between 1 and 60 inclusive, that value is returned. I'm running into the following issues though:

If I input all integers, only the first value is returned:

```
Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? 99
Interval must be between 1 and 60.
Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? -20
Interval must be between 1 and 60.
Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? 5
99
```

If I use other data types causing `int_a = int(a)` to fail, I get a return of None:

```
Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? 5555.9999
Interval must be an integer between 1 and 60.
Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? -5
Interval must be between 1 and 60.
Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? 5
None
```

I'm having trouble tracking the contents of the variables through this. Basically the first variable that passes the 'int_a = int(a)' becomes what is returned, regardless of the recursion.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You must explicitly return the result of the inner call. Also "int_a" is a local variable. It has its own value for each call of the function and isn't shared between inner and outer calls.

Comment: `return get_seconds()`, not just `get_seconds()`.  Also you should use `return None` instead of `exit()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly return the inner recursive call value too. In the last line of function use `return get_seconds()` instead of `get_seconds()`

Answer (score 3):

See [Wasif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295422/7505395) for why yours does not work - your code does not return values on all code paths.

Using recursion for this task is bad, use a simple loop and break/return from it:

```
def get_seconds():
    while True:
        a = input("Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? ")
        if a.lower() == "q":
            exit()
        try:
            int_a = int(a)
            if 1 <= int_a <= 60:   # return if valid, this leaves the while loop 
                return int_a
        except ValueError:         # catch specific errors
            print("Interval must be an integer between 1 and 60.")

c = get_seconds()
```

You can find more on this in [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: I was writing a similar answer. Will just leave a link explaining the concept here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion

Answer (score 1):

You have problems on several levels.  The *process* problem is that you've written a four-lobed subroutine without testing the individual code blocks.  The *structural* problem is that you're using recursion to do a job better suited for simple iteration.  See [iterate until valid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

The *functional* problem is that the only time you return a value is from the top level of calls:

```
print("Interval must be between 1 and 60.")
get_seconds()
return(int_a)
```

Your code here is clearly dysfunctional

- issue an error message
- recur to get new input ... and ignore any returned value
- return the *local* value that made you print the error message.

In a recursion situation, you would take the value you get from the recursive call and pass it back up the call stack.

```
print('error')
return(get_seconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_seconds():

        a = input("Run how often in seconds (1-60, q to Quit)? ")
        if a.lower() == "q":
         exit()

        try:
            int_a = int(a)
            if 1 <= int_a <= 60:
                print(int_a)
                exit()

            else:
                print('Interval must be between 1 and 60.')
                get_seconds()

        except ValueError:
            print("Interval must be an integer between 1 and 60.")
            get_seconds()


c = get_seconds()
print(get_seconds())
```

Hi.
it will solve your problem,
I just edit somethings in code.
just fix indents by yourself.
good luck!